# Open new page with post data

Tags: php, post

In PHP, i want to open more that one window and each one of them need to recieve different post data.

i know how to redirect a page via header location + Get DATA, but i really need to be able to send POST data.

EDIT:

```
Graph
       |-Page with post 1
Main --|-Page with post 2
       |-Page with post 3
```

so basically 1 page goes and open 3 pages with different post data on each. must be done server Side.

Comment: can you be more specific? do you want to send data from one page to multiple other pages? does the sent data need to be displayed straight up in those pages?

Comment: You aren't clear on the direction. Do you want the POST to be from Child -> Parent or from Parent -> Child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use three forms? ;-) Code tested, works.

```
<form method='post' action='http://<sever>/post1.php' id='action_frm1' name="action_frm1" target="_blank">
  <input type='hidden' name='param1' value='hello'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='param2' value='world'/>
</form>
<form method='post' action='http://<sever>/post2.php' id='action_frm2'  name="action_frm2" target="_blank">
  <input type='hidden' name='param1' value='hello2'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='param2' value='world2'/>
</form>
<form method='post' action='http://<sever>/post3.php' id='action_frm3'  name="action_frm3" target="_blank">
  <input type='hidden' name='param1' value='hello3'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='param2' value='world3'/>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
     function makePostRedirect() {
       document.getElementById('action_frm1').submit();
       document.getElementById('action_frm2').submit();
       document.getElementById('action_frm3').submit();
     }
     makePostRedirect()
</script>
```

Of course, if you want post data via serverside usefull link will be this: http://noobflash.com/server-side-post-with-php/

Comment: the problem remain in the need of an HTML page here, but i will accept your answer because of the link wich helped me.

Comment: Had to go to the wayback machine for that URL https://web.archive.org/web/20121003223211/http://noobflash.com/server-side-post-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

you may use the following trick:

```
<form method='post' action='action.php' id='action_frm'>
  <input type='hidden' name='param1' value='hello'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='param2' value='world'/>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
     function makePostRedirect() {
       document.getElementById('action_frm').submit();
     }
</script>
```

Comment: This answers the question of how do i automatically post some data, but doesn't answer the question of how do i open windows that post data.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a workaround by calling window.open to some stub PHP pages that can then use some JavaScript to call a form post.  What your asking can not really be done in PHP because PHP is server side and not front end.  Your looking for a much more JavaScript reliant solution.

Comment: so i need to do something like this? PHP => javascript => Open new page with Post?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a single POST to a new window by putting a `target="_new"` on the `<form>` element. It won't validate, but it will open ONE new window and submit the form data via that window.

For multiple windows, you'll have to hack together some JS to open the multiple windows, insert a form with a copy of the data you want to have posted in that window, then trigger the posts individually.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

Original page ---opens---> page 1 ---opens---> page 2 ---opens---> page 3

Each page passes the data for the remaining pages.  Search for javascript pop-up code that works and runs on page open.

Comment: because the objective is to run multiple page at once so they can simulate multiple requests at once, also to generate multiple required callbacks